# Tips on creating Microsoft Office 2011 Templates/Themes?

Tags: template-design, microsoft-powerpoint, microsoft-office, microsoft-word

I'm attempting to create some basic branded templates in Microsoft Office (Word and PowerPoint) to be deployed for office use. Just some colours, and basic typography hierarchy so people can easily create quick documents themselves.

It seems that in order to create a theme for Word, you have to make one in PowerPoint - however it seems in Microsoft Office 2011 for Mac you can only create colour themes, not font themes (not supported for some reason).

Has anyone tried to create some themes for Microsoft Office 2011, and have any tips on how to approach this, or some workarounds for this?

Comment: It seems like you can do that only Windows; according to this https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_other-mso_mac/create-font-themes-in-word-2011-for-macintosh/d79c351d-de74-4bf4-acb6-70a196ca039d

Answer (score 1):

I'm not a Microsoft Word expert but the text stylesheet I use are in the "Toolbox", and if you click on each style, you will see that you can add it to the template.

My screenshot is with the "legacy" style (I prefer it) but I guess you can figure out where that toolbox on the recent interface instead!

[image: How to add text and font styles to Microsoft Word templates]

Answer (score 0):

To make a Word template you only need Word.

The easiest way to do this is to make a new document, make the necessary changes in the style's, for Heading 1, 2, normal, etc.

Save as a simple word doc or docx file with a clear name: TemplateForInternalComunucation-2018.doc

Probably protect it as read-only and send it like that. People could simply rename the doc when making a new document.

Answer (score -3):

If you do much of this, check out "Building PowerPoint Templates" by Swinford and Terberg. It's available on Amazon and from Que directly; other places as well, I imagine. It's primarily Windows-oriented but they do explain the Mac side of things somewhat.  You may find that it's simpler to develop templates/themes under Windows PPT, then test them on Mac.

Comment: Interesting that my reply was downvoted when it directly answers the original question: "Has anyone tried to create some themes for Microsoft Office 2011, and have any tips on how to approach this, or some workarounds for this?"  The authors of the book I recommended explain how to create themes for both WIndows and Mac PowerPoint.

Comment: Probably because you do not answer the question instead you say "look at this book" so it's more suitable as a comment. You could write an answer here and link to the book for reference, or quote something parts the book.

Comment: @Luciano Re "link to the book": two seconds with Google will locate the book for anyone interested in looking at it.  Re "you could write an answer here" ... Sure. If I had time and room to write an entire book chapter.  A book chapter that someone else has already written. Some questions are too broad to answer in the time and space available here. This is certainly one of them. If recommendations of other resources aren't welcome when they DO answer the OP's question, delete my reply.  Sometimes the nannying here goes over the top.

Comment: Not nannying and I didn't downvote, just took my time to explain to you what I think are reasons to the downvotes. I thought the point of answers was to actually answer what's being asked, and additional info / links to complement it. Check other questions / answers / SE sites / https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer

Comment: either that or flag the question as too broad.

Comment: Thanks for the non-downvote, then.  ;-)  Still, sometimes a broad question is a valid one, but it begs a broad answer. If I need help with something, I'd much prefer that someone point me at resources that would provide the help rather than ignoring my question because it can't be answered fully in the space provided.  So I respond in that same spirit.

Comment: My point is, don't just point to the book without telling what we're gonna find there, sometimes a short outline of how to solve the problem is enough to answer the question. It's the same as answering with just a link: what if the link dies? What if the OP can't buy the book right now? An answer should be self-sustained even without these external resources.

Comment: I understand your point.  But from my POV, it came down to a choice between answering as I did or not answering at all. The book has the answers OP's looking for, I don't have the time, energy or need to summarize it. If the OP can't buy the book right now, that's unfortunate but it doesn't mean that the book doesn't hold answers for others who might see this thread.  Answers should *ideally* be self-contained/sustained, yes. But that's not always possible, and today's complete answers are liable to be invalidated by technical change tomorrow. Let the OP decide whether the answer's helpful.

Comment: @SteveRindsberg that's why it should be a comment. There's nothing wrong with copying and pasting your answer into a comment. You'll even get your rep back that you lost from the down votes. It's annoying but that's the rules of the site. Keeps answers better in the long run.